# Adding git hooks to google cloud repo

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, githooks

One of the things that comes with google cloud are [git repos](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/). Is it possible to add hooks to this repo? I'd like to incoming pushes, but I don't know how to get access to `.git/hooks`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it if you host your code on [git-hub/bitbucket](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/connecting-hosted-repositories). Then you will be able to use the git hooks.

Google source has this feature (Object Change Notification) instead of hooks:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification

Comment: The change notification is for things in storage buckets, right? Is the source repository feature implicitly in some storage bucket? I didn't think it was. It doesn't show up in the bucket browser anywhere.

Comment: read the first link and see if you can store your code externally

Comment: Yes, your method would work. I was hoping there was a way to do so without externally hosting the code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pub/sub notifications instead of the webhook.

In my case, I created a pub/sub which is triggered when the repository is updated.
The pub/sub will call a cloud function that makes a post request to codemagic.io CI/CD to initiate a cloud build.

pub/sub notification: https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-adding-pubsub-notifications

You can get the information like the updated branch name, author, etc, in the notification payload.
https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pubsub-notifications#notification_example

Comment: you won't be able to reject changes with pub/sub notifications

Comment: @hegebut But this is the only way possible with the Google Cloud Source Repository, please suggest if you know any alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server settings, if you use VM not cloud repo of GCloud. https://www.linux.com/LEARN/HOW-RUN-YOUR-OWN-GIT-SERVER You need to install git-core also and add git user to system. I had spended more then day before unserstanding about.